# Encode WhiteSpace in Razor Dynamic Attributes

Tags: razor, whitespace, html-encode

I have dynamic HTML attributes generated using Razor.

Everything seems to work fine except when I generate an attribute value with a whitespace within like:

```
item.Name = "Organisation Structure";
```

When I then try to render this value in a dynamic attribute, Razor thinks that the text after the whitespace is another entirely different attribute.

```
     <a href="@item.Url" @(!item.HasSubItems ? "data-tab-title=" + item.Name : "")></a>
```

Which renders wrongly as:

```
<a href="/index" data-tab-title="Organisation" structure=""></a>
```

instead of like this:

```
<a href="/index" data-tab-title="Organisation structure"></a>
```

I have even tried to use `Html.Encode(item.Name)` like below:

```
<a href="@item.Url" @(!item.HasSubItems ? "data-tab-title=" + Html.Encode(item.Name) : "")></a>
```

Please, any solutions to this problem will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply doing a `String.Replace("","&nbsp")`

```
<a @(!item.HasSubItems ? "data-tab-title=" + item.Name.Replace(" ","&nbsp") : "") href="@item.Url" ></a>
```

This solved the problem rather nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You could try :

```
@{
  var dynamicLink = string.Format("<a href='{0}' {1}></a>", item.Url, (!item.HasSubItems)? "data-tab-title='" + item.Name +"'" : "");
 }

@Html.Raw(dynamicLink)
```